What is the に doing in ''元に''?

会社の小林さんの印象を元に描いてみた
Been trying to figure out this sentence for a while. What is the に particle's role here and what would it translate to? It's targeting 元 but I just don't get what it means. The verb is not intransitive either.
I know the question might sound weird but I am completely confused.

Somehow this sounds to me like context is missing.  Almost like this is a relative clause lifted from a sentence.  Could you add in the add context?

Added the image and the rest of the context although I don't think it changes that much for the meaning

I think 印象を元に is just abbreviated for 印象を元にして.  Does that make better sense for you?

The image helped.  I was expecting something like 会社の小林さんの印象を元に描いてみた本 or 会社の小林さんの印象を元に描いてみたノート which the image seems to confirm.

yeah another source said ''元に'' meant based on and due to that I was really confused on how the ni functioned here. But I did not provide any image for context so it really depends if that is the case. I tried searching up sentences with 元に but couldn't find any that was similar to this.

This is part of the AをBに construction, which is a pattern that is very easy for learners to miss.

Meaning of ~を~に(して) / ~を~として / ~を~にする / ~を~とする / ~を~にした / ~を~とした
Meaning and transitivity of ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる

So 会社の小林さんの印象を元に means "with 会社の小林さんの印象 as 元". And 元 in this context means "base", "source (of inspiration)" or "motif".

会社の小林さんの印象を元に描いてみた。
I tried drawing (it) with my impression of you at the office as the base.
→ I tried drawing (it) based on my impression of you at the office.


Yeah I have never learned nor heard about this before through any grammar guides so reading this now makes a lot of sense

The image would suggest that the one individual is describing the notebook she is holding.
I feel this could be taken any number of ways depending on more of the context.
Obviously someone wrote out some thoughts about Kobayashi.  That might be the character speaking, that might be someone else, that might be Kobayashi.  Context should make that clearer.
Per @chocolate's comment, a more natural choice is "I" given that the verb is of the form してみた.  With that assumption in mind, I would parse the sentence as follows.

[This notebook is in which] I tried sketch [it] out based on Kobayashi's impressions [of things]

as if she were saying

これは会社の小林さんの印象を元に描いてみたもの/ノートです


but would that mean 元に is the same as the 元にして to mean ''based on'' ? And if so I wonder why it was abbreviated like this cause I haven't seen it before

@HoodIntercooledSubaru Not quite.  The notebook is "based on Kobayashi's impressions".  "Aを元にして" is an idiomatic expression meaning "based on A".  I'm assuming that the character omitted して

I see, I didn't even know omitting those parts were grammatically allowed but if this is the case then it makes more sense

「書いてみた」ではなく「描いてみた」ですから、ノートの向こう側のページに、絵が描かれているんでしょう。「会社の小林さんの印象を元にして（私が）（この、小林さんの絵を）描いてみた。」と言って、絵を見せてるんですね。会社にいるときの小林さんの印象が描かれているので、メイドカフェの店員さんにとっては、「店に来る時とは違う、私が知らない（会社での）（ストイックな）小林さんの一面」なのだと思いますがどうでしょう。

@chocolate Corrected.

@chocolate I pondered that.  I was tempted to translate as "I".  With only the barest of context, how do you decide between 私が and 小林が as the one who drew the sketches?  It hadn't occurred to me that this was a "maid" in a "maid cafe".  Now that I look back at the picture, I can see that.

「～してみた。」って、主語なしだったら普通は主語は一人称かな、という感じが‥
